# setting up DNS to serve domaina.com from domaina.domainb.com

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have two domains. I want them both use the same hosting plan I have. The other domain should locate under the other, but it must look independent. How do I set the dns for the second domain?

Answer (score 0):

Set a CNAME to the same webserver, then configure the web server to serve the appropriate content for each `host`.